# RANKX not working properly when applying filter

Tags: powerbi

My RANKX function is not working properly when I apply a Brand filter. For example, without filters I get the following rank

[image]

But when I apply a Brand filter, to select only Pure Sunfarms, Redecan, and Good Supply the ranking changes:

[image]

My formula is:

```
Rank (Total Sales) Brand = 
IF(
    HASONEVALUE(
        'OCS-daily-2018-2023'[brand]
    ),
    RANKX(
        ALL(
            'OCS-daily-2018-2023'[brand]
        ),
        [Total Sales],
        ,
        DESC,
        Dense
    )
)
```

and my model looks like this:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you add a minimum example data that reproduces your issue along with whatever measure definitions you are using for `Total Sales`. What happens if you swap out `ALL` with `ALLSELECTED`?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ALL('OCS-daily-2018-2023'[brand])` with `ALL('OCS-daily-2018-2023')`

```
Rank (Total Sales) Brand = 
IF(
    HASONEVALUE(
        'OCS-daily-2018-2023'
    ),
    RANKX(
        ALL(
            'OCS-daily-2018-2023'[brand]
        ),
        [Total Sales],
        ,
        DESC,
        Dense
    )
)
```